# What is the meaning of placing a sign on the chest?

Tags: jesus, revelation, exodus, moses, deuteronomy

A priest wears on his chest a breastplate, and inscribed on it are the precious gemstones of the twelve tribes of Israel. In the visions of John called the book of revelation one wears on his chest words saying the word of G-D. What is the meaning of placing a sign on the chest?

Revelation 1:13
and in the middle of the lampstands I saw one like a son of man, clothed in a robe reaching to the feet, and girded across His chest with a golden sash.

"breastplate of judgment" - Exodus 28:30) had each of its precious stones engraved with the name of one of the twelve tribes of Israel (Leviticus 8:7 - 9, Exodus 28:17 - 20, 39:10 - 13).

Comment: I find your question hard to follow because you have not quoted where this verse comes in Revelation. Also I have had a short look and can't find such a verse. So please edit into your question where "wears on his chest" comes from.

Comment: @C.Stroud the reference is included now.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what question you are asking.  Is it about the OT high priest's breat plate of the golden sash around Jesus' chest?  They are different!

Comment: @Dottard I guess that having a golden sash and 12 tribes of Israel on the chest is a sign of authority and one that has authority

Comment: Except that golden sash is just that - a golden sash - it is NOT a breastplate made of linen as per the OT high priest's garment and no precious stones are on the sash of Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

I do not find a passage in Revelation describing a priest wearing a vestment with God's name inscribed. However, in Exodus, both Aaron and the other priests are described as wearing a sash and headgear with an inscribed plate on their foreheads. This particular plate, reading "holy to the Lord,"  was not part of the breastpiece described in the OP, but of a priestly turban or crown.

> 7 They made the tunics of finely woven linen for Aaron and his sons,
> 28 and the turban of fine linen, and the decorated caps of fine linen,
> and the linen breeches of fine twisted linen, 29 and the sash of fine
> twisted linen, and blue and purple and scarlet material, the work of
> the weaver, just as the Lord had commanded Moses. 30 *They made the
> plate of the holy crown of pure gold, and inscribed it like the
> engravings of a signet, “Holy to the Lord*.” 31 They fastened a blue
> cord to it, to fasten it on the turban above, just as the Lord had
> commanded Moses. (Ex. 28)

**If a priest is described elsewhere in the Bible as wearing a plate with God's name written on it, this would probably be related to the above.**